# I can’t understand how the level of water in a cup with ice cube floating would stay the same when it dissolves?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

it’s my first time taking physics, so I’m a no expert, I need your help.

I’m facing problems understanding the question below, which states that the answer is “c” and the water level should stay the same. But that makes no sense to me and I was able to prove so numerically.

I know I’m wrong, but I don’t know where or how, what am I missing out?
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e6zN.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ice takes more volume than liquid water, so the density is lower. This means that while the ice cube floats, its emerged volume represents nothing but this very excess in volume that water takes when it's under its solid form. Then when the ice cube melts, this excess in volume disappears, and so the volume of water+melted ice cube is just the volume of the immersed side of the ice cube plus the initial volume of water. Thus water's level doesn't raise.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of the icecube is bigger as the volume of the water it occupies. But if the icecube turns into water it will occupy exactly the volume it occupied when an icecube. So there will be no in- or decrease in water level. Only the tip of the icecube will be gone. Water occupies less volume than ice.